# Is it good exapmple of encapsulation in C# ? Or should i use public set; get;?

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation

I want to write a person class.
I am not sure when should I use public set on a property.

In the following example, should I use `public set` on `Name` property ?

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
    public Person[] Parents 
    { 
        get { return (Person[])Parents.Clone(); }
        private set { Parents = value; } 
    }

    public Person(string Name, DateTime DateOfBirth, Person[] parents=null)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
        Parents = parents;
    }
}
```

Comment: Names can change (marriage, legal change of name, etc.), so you should consider having some way of changing the name.

Comment: Only if you want Name to be set outside of this class. Nothing wrong with having a get only property with a private setter.

Comment: [MSDN Auto-Implemented Property's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: Please ask for code reviews in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You shouldn’t just clone the array on the `Parents` getter. Consider returning a read-only `IEnumerable` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to able to change the property from a code which relies outside the class - yes.

```
class program
{
    public void main()
    {
       Person p = new Person("New Born", DateTime.Now());
       :
       :
       p.Name="John";
    }
}
```

However, if the name should never change from the outside and only from within the class code - no.

**As a general guideline:** 
*If the property setter is public,*
 *- You usually don't need to add a constructor parameter to force setting it.*
*If you do wish for some reason to force setting it,*
 *- it probably don't need to be public.*
But that's just a general guideline - not a "strong" rule.